# Uniformly local Sobolev spaces and interpolation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, interpolation

Let $d\in\mathbb{N}^+$, $s\geq 0$, and consider the uniformly local Sobolev space

$$H^s_{u,loc}(\mathbb{R}^d):=\{f\in H^s_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^d)\,s.t.\,\|f\|_{H^s_{u,loc}}:=\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^d} \|f\|_{H^s(B_x)} < \infty\},$$

where $B_x$ is the ball of radius one centered at x. I expect that, given $0\leq s_0<s_1$, $\theta\in(0,1)$, and setting $s_{\theta}:=\theta s_1+(1-\theta)s_0$ the following interpolation inequality holds true:

$$(*)\quad\|f\|_{H^{s_{\theta}}}\leq \|f\|_{H^{s_{1}}_{u,loc}}^{\theta}\|f\|^{1-\theta}_{H^{s_{0}}} $$

Observe that, replacing $H^{s_{1}}_{u,loc}$ with $H^{s_1}$, we reduce to the classical interpolation inequality for Sobolev space.

**Is estimate (*) actually true? In case, is there an explicit reference?**

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: This is not true. Take for example $s_0=0$, $s_1=2$ and $s_\theta=1$; the inequality would imply that a bounded function with second derivatives in $L^p$ has a p-summable gradient, which is not true. In $1d$ (and for $p=1$) one can take $u'(x)=(1/x) \sin(\sqrt x)$ for $x \ge 1$.

Comment: @ Giorgio Metafune. Thank you for the comment. It is not obvious to me why $\int_1^{\infty}|u'(x)|=+\infty$.

Comment: This because $\int_1^\infty \frac{|sin (\sqrt x)|}{x}dx=\int_1^\infty \frac{|\sin t|}{t^2} 2tdt=\infty$ (change variable $x=t^2)$. However the function $u$ defined as the integral from $1$ to $x$ of the same function without the absolute value is bounded because of the oscillation of the sinus, and $u''$ is integrable.

Comment: Ok thank you, a last doubt: why it's enough that $u$ is bounded? In principle you should check that $u\in L^1(1,\infty)$

Comment: Actually, it is also still not clear to me why $\int_1^{\infty}|\sin(t)|t^{-1}dt=+\infty$. Because in principle there still is some oscillation which could prevent the integral to diverge.

Comment: Just take our $u$ and multiply by smooth cut off functions $\eta_n$ which are 1 until $n$ and zero after $n+1$. The interpolation inequaitly cannot hold for $u\eta_n$ with the same constant (the sup-norm are preserved, the norms of the second derivatives are uniformly bounded but those of the first deriveatives blow up). Concerning the divergence of the integral, split it in  series (between $k\pi$ and $(k+1)\pi$) and estimate $1/t$ by $C/k$. The armonic series appears.

Comment: But the $L^1$-norm of $u\eta_n$ could diverge as well. What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, they will do; but the local $L^1$ norms stay bounded, since they are controlled by the sup norm.

Comment: Oh sorry, I realised now that I put the local norm on the lower order derivatives. Your example is clear now. I'm actually interested in the opposite situation, i.e. when the local norm is on the higher derivatives. Do you still think the estimate is false? In any case it would be nice to see an example for $p\neq 1$, as $p=1$ may be pathological for some interpolation inequality. Thank you a lot for the help!

Comment: Again it is not true since the p-integrability of $Du$ does not follow from that of $u$ and, say, boundedness of second derivatives. Take $$u=\sum_k \delta_k^2 \phi \left (\frac{x-k}{\delta_k}\right)$$ where $\phi$ is a fixed function with support in $[-1,1]$. Such a function has bounded second derivative and choosing appropriately the $\delta_k$ one has that $u \in L^2$ but $u'\not \in L^2$.

Comment: @ Giorgio Metafune: thank you!